# Bitmap getByteCount Issue

Tags: java, android

I'm downloading pictures from the internet and I want to see the size of this picture I downloaded (in KB). But very wrong results. For example original image size 500 KB and Bitmap getbytecount value is turns out to 1 mb..

Do I know the size of a bitmap **without compression?** (I tried; Glide, Picasso, HttpRequest)

Example Original Image Link:
https://images.pexels.com/photos/1363876/pexels-photo-1363876.jpeg

3,44 MB (3.612.872 bayt)

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).dontAnimate().skipMemoryCache(true);

 Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1363876/pexels-photo-1363876.jpeg")
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .apply(options)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        photo_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        photo_view.setImageBitmap(resource);

                        Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) photo_view.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

                        byte[] imageByte = stream.toByteArray();
                        long lenghtBmp = imageByte.length;

                        sizekb = (int) (lenghtBmp / 1024);
                        sizemb = sizekb / 1024;

                        Log.d("TAG_lenght", "\t" + lenghtBmp);
                        Log.d("TAG_res_getbyte", "\t" + resource.getByteCount());
                        Log.d("TAG_bmp_getbyte", "\t" + bmp.getByteCount());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                    }
                });
```

Logcat Results..

D/TAG_lenght:   3907064

D/TAG_res_getbyte:  42672000

D/TAG_bmp_getbyte:  42672000

Comment: Please add some examples of the code you've tried, and the output they produce with against one or more sample images. For the image(s), please give their size as stored on disk, along with their width, height and number of bits/bytes per pixel.

Comment: You can try this
(bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight()) / 1024;

Comment: Pictures mostly reside in files. And mostly they are not bitmaps. So if you convert a .jpg file to a bitmap you get someting twenty times as big. Dowload your picture files to disk and you will see that they have equal file size.

Comment: I added.. @TripeHound

Comment: Those numbers seem consistent... 4,000 pixels wide x 2667 pixels high x 4 bytes-per-pixel = 42,672,000 bytes for the "raw" image (42MB). Compressing to about 3.7MiB as a JPG seems reasonable. Are you looking for anything other than one of these numbers?

Comment: I would like to get the size of the original image only. How can i do that? @TripeHound